# Научить человека обходить препятствия (canvas) 2D

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, искусственный-интеллект

## Введение

Существует 2D экосистема с "человеком" и неким количеством "зомби". Они представлены квадратами 50х50 внутри `<canvas>` 1000х1000 пикселей.

Зомби передвигаются хаотично. Задача человека - пробраться в пункт Б из пункта А (что по сути тоже квадраты). При этом обходя остальные квадраты (т.е. зомби)

### Описание проблемы

Несколько дней я уже пытаюсь научить человека обходить зомби, но, к сожалению, не получается выработать алгоритм принятия решения, куда идти (учитывая прошлый опыт прогулок).

### Что надо

Пишу сюда в ожидании, что услышу какие-либо мысли и идеи, которые получится реализовать.

## Код

```js
class Rect {
  width;
  height;
  x;
  y;

  constructor(canvas, width = 50, height = 50, x = 0, y = 0) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.canvas = canvas;
  }
}


class Direction extends Rect {
  constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
    super();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}

class Human extends Rect {

  pathClosed;
  history;
  direction;
  obstaclesMap;

  static isNegative() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
  }

  constructor(canvas) {
    super(canvas);

    // Запоминаю, где я был
    this.history = {};
    this.history.x = new Set();
    this.history.y = new Set();
    this.history.last = {};

    this.direction = new Direction(0, 0); // Ближайшие координаты, куда я пойду
    this.endPoint = new Direction(0, 0); // Пункт назначения

    this.pathClosed = true;

    this.visibleArea = 200; // Насколько ограничена дальность видимости

    // Устанавливаю точку своего отправления А
    this.x = 400;
    this.y = 400;
  }

  go() {
    this.updateHistory(); // Запоминаю, где я был
    this.planMovement(); // думаю, куда идти - определяю маршрут
    this.move(); // меняю свои координаты
  }

  updateHistory() {
    // Запомнить, где я был
    this.history.last.x = this.x;
    this.history.last.y = this.y;
    this.history.x.add(this.x);
    this.history.y.add(this.y);
  }

  defineEndPoint() {
    let
      path; // для расчета координат

    do {
      // Определим X
      path = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.canvas.width + 1));
      this.endPoint.x = Human.isNegative() ? this.history.last.x - path : this.history.last.x + path;

      // Определим Y
      path = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.canvas.height + 1));
      this.endPoint.y = Human.isNegative() ? this.history.last.y - path : this.history.last.y + path;

      // Предусмотреть невозможность выхода за границы холста
      this.endPoint.x = this.endPoint.x + this.width > this.canvas.width ? this.canvas.width - this.width : this.endPoint.x;
      this.endPoint.x = this.endPoint.x + this.width < this.width ? 0 : this.endPoint.x;
      this.endPoint.y = this.endPoint.y + this.height > this.canvas.height ? this.canvas.height - this.height : this.endPoint.y;
      this.endPoint.y = this.endPoint.y + this.height < this.height ? 0 : this.endPoint.y;
    }
    while (this.isCollision(this.endPoint.x, this.endPoint.y));
    // Обозначим старт нашего шествия
    this.pathClosed = false;
  }

  setObstaclesMap(map) {
    // Теперь человек знает координаты зомби
    this.obstaclesMap = map;
  }

  /*
   * Определяет, есть ли вторжение на территорию другого квадрата
   * Возвращает true | false
   * @param dirX - потенциальное значение X для сверки со всеми X препятствий
   * @param dirY - потенциальное значение Y для сверки со всеми Y препятствий
   */
  isCollision(dirX, dirY) {

    let top,
      bottom,
      colX,
      colY;

    for (let [x, y] of this.obstaclesMap) {

      // учитываем width квадратов

      top = x + this.width;
      bottom = x - this.width;

      colX = dirX > bottom && dirX < top;

      top = y - this.height;
      bottom = y + this.height;

      colY = dirY > top && dirY < bottom;

      // Если пересечение
      if (colX && colY) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    // Нет пересечения
    return false;
  }

  planMovement() {
    // Самое сложное место
    // На этом шаге требуется ваша помощь
    // В пределах этого метода - лишь наброски

    let x,
      y;

    // visibleArea === 200

    x = this.x;
    y = this.y;

    x = x < this.endPoint.x ? x + 1 : x - 1;
    y = y < this.endPoint.y ? y + 1 : y - 1;

    do {
      x = x < this.endPoint.x ? x + 1 : x - 1;

      if (this.isCollision(x, y)) {
        Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) ? --x : ++x;
      }

    }
    while (this.isCollision(x, y))


    while (this.isCollision(x, y)) {
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) ? --y : ++y;
    }


    this.direction.x = x;
    this.direction.y = y;

    // Detect distance
    // I gotta reduce that distance
    // distanceX = Math.abs(this.endPoint.x - this.x);
    // distanceY = Math.abs(this.endPoint.y - this.y);


  }

  move() {
    // Я двигаюсь в direction
    // Потому что считаю это самым актуальным направлением сейчас в зависимости от обстоятельств
    // Я могу менять свое мнение, и координаты direction будут меняться
    // Главное - последний direction должен соответствовать endPoint

    if (this.x < this.direction.x) {
      ++this.x;
    }

    if (this.x > this.direction.x) {
      --this.x;
    }

    if (this.y < this.direction.y) {
      ++this.y;
    }

    if (this.y > this.direction.y) {
      --this.y;
    }

    if (this.endPoint.x === this.x && this.endPoint.y === this.y) {
      // Я добрался до пункта назначения
      this.pathClosed = true;
      console.log("Path closed");
    }

  }

}

class Obstacle extends Rect {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

class CanvasMap {

  context;
  obstacles;

  constructor(id = "canvas") {
    this.context = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
    this.obstacles = new Map();
  }

  drawRect(x, y, beginPath = true, instance) {

    if (beginPath) {
      this.context.beginPath();
    }

    if (instance instanceof Obstacle) {
      this.context.fillStyle = '#728073';
    }

    if (instance instanceof Direction) {
      this.context.fillStyle = '#79de7e';
    }

    if (instance instanceof Human) {
      this.context.fillStyle = '#53bde8';
      // Зачистка "шлейфа"
      this.context.clearRect(instance.history.last.x, instance.history.last.y, instance.width, instance.height);
    }
    // Рисовать квадрат
    this.context.fillRect(x, y, instance.width, instance.height);
  }


  drawRandomObstacles(amount = 5, width = 0, rectWidth = 50) {

    let i,
      x,
      y;

    i = 0;

    while (i < amount) {
      i++;

      let obstacle = new Obstacle(this.context.canvas, 50, 50);

      do {
        // Todo check if already exists the same one
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width + 1));
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (width + 1));

      } while (x + rectWidth > width || y + rectWidth > width);

      // Запомнить координаты зомби
      this.obstacles.set(x, y);
      // Нарисовать зомби
      this.drawRect(x, y, true, obstacle);
    }


  }

}

class Ecosystem {

  canvas; // Сам холст
  canvasMap; // Отрисовщик
  human;

  static run() {
    let ecosystem = new Ecosystem();

    console.log("ecosystem.human : ", ecosystem.human);
    console.log("ecosystem.canvasMap : ", ecosystem.canvasMap);

    // Добавить зомби на карту
    ecosystem.canvasMap.drawRandomObstacles(10, ecosystem.canvas.width, 50);
    // Передать данные о координатах зомби человеку
    ecosystem.human.setObstaclesMap(ecosystem.canvasMap.obstacles);

    // Записать точку отправления из пункта А
    ecosystem.human.updateHistory();
    // Установить пункт назначения Б
    ecosystem.human.defineEndPoint();

    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    function render() {
      // Рисует пункт Б
      ecosystem.canvasMap.drawRect(ecosystem.human.endPoint.x, ecosystem.human.endPoint.y, true, ecosystem.human.endPoint);

      // Рисует новые координаты человека
      ecosystem.canvasMap.drawRect(ecosystem.human.x, ecosystem.human.y, true, ecosystem.human);

      // Передвинуть человека
      ecosystem.human.go();

      requestAnimationFrame(render);
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    this.canvasMap = new CanvasMap();
    this.canvas = this.canvasMap.context.canvas
    this.human = new Human(this.canvas);
  }

}

Ecosystem.run();
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#canvas {
  border: 1px #b0b0b0 solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Если у вас квадраты и пошаговая логика, то поиск в ширину (он же волновой алгоритм) может дать вам кратчайший путь из точки А в точку Б.